# Libgdx adding a cell to a table

Tags: java, libgdx

[I'm trying to add label here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WniNW.png)

```
 Label missionTitle = new Label(mission.title, skin);
    Label missionDesct = new Label(mission.desct, skin);
    Label remainDay = new Label(TaskManager.getRemainMissionDay(mission.deadLine) + "day remain", skin);

    missionDesct.setFontScale(width * 1.4f / 1080);
    remainDay.setFontScale(width * 1.2f / 1080);
    missionDesct.setWrap(true);


    Table table = new Table();
    table.debug();
    table.background(new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("image/imgray.png"))));
    table.add(missionTitle).width(width / 1.1f);
    table.row();
    table.add(missionDesct).width(width / 1.1f);
    table.row();
    table.add(remainDay).width(width/2.3f).left();
```

for that i'm adding this lines;

```
  Label goldLabel = new Label("30 gold", skin);
    table.add(goldLabel);
```

But result is;
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmO6N.png)

How can i add a new cell over there?
I tried to adding ".width(width/2);" but it's not working.

```
    ...
    table.row();
    table.add(remainDay).width(width/2.3f).left();
    Label goldLabel = new Label("30 gold", skin);
    table.add(goldLabel).width(width/2.3f);
```

Comment: Can you try this table.add(remainDay, goldLabel); ?

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating a table with the 2 labels and then adding the table into the container table.

Example -

```
Table nestedTable = new Table();

nestedTable.add(remainDay).width(THE_WIDTH);
nestedTable.add(goldLabel).width(THE_WIDTH);

mainTable.add(nestedTable);
```

You can play around more with this to get the desired result :)

This class can also help - [HorizontalGroup](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/HorizontalGroup.html)

Answer (score 0):

Finally i understand my mistake.I was trying to add 2 cell to a row.But that was effecting the other row's cell count.I changed my code to this and solved;

```
 Table table = new Table();
    table.background(new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("image/imgray.png"))));
    table.add(missionTitle).width(width/1.5f).left();
    table.add(new TextButton("!", skin)).height(height/23).width(width / 5).right();
    table.row().fillX();
    table.add(missionDesct).expandX();
    table.add(goldAndExp).right();
    table.row();
    table.add(remainDay).left();
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luzWf.png)

I'll be happy if someone fix my grammar problems.